# I/Counters( 4623): exceeded sample count in FrameTime 2 E/FrameEvents( 4623): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

guys I'm working on InDriver app clone. Today I was making it's UI screens that in drawer. But when suddenly I happened to see an error.Now I'm unable to navigate through new routes. I don't know if i made too much screens or anything else. also old routes are working fine. If any one have ever seen this error please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Also see picture of this error below: